# Pagespeed not compressing images

Tags: page-speed, nginx

Original image `bart-had-a-groove.gif` size is `753.43 KB`.

Processed image `bart-had-a-groove.gif.pagespeed.ce.gB3ARqAHA8.gif` size is still `753.43 KB`.

Mods used:

```
  pagespeed DisableRewriteOnNoTransform off;

  pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_images;
  pagespeed EnableFilters sprite_images;
  pagespeed EnableFilters insert_image_dimensions;
  pagespeed EnableFilters resize_images;
  pagespeed EnableFilters resize_rendered_image_dimensions;
  pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_images;
  pagespeed EnableFilters strip_image_color_profile;
  pagespeed EnableFilters strip_image_meta_data;
```

The file gets renamed and headers contain the pagespeed, so pagespeed is working.

Could it be that the original image was already compressed to the max or something?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to make any difference, but you appear to have the `rewrite_images` filter twice? Shouldn't the `rewrite_images` filter also convert GIF to PNG?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for noticing. My GIF is animated and contains more than one frame, and documentation states I should use `convert_to_webp_animated` at https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/reference-image-optimize instead. I added the line, but I still get the `.gif` output.

Comment: @user3108268 have you flushed the cache, restarted apache and service memcached? since, you will need to since those previous rules and results are now cached.

Comment: @SimonHayter I did. Anyway, I came up with the solution going with MP4. Smallest size and more supported by majority browsers than webm or webp according to `caniuse.com`. Just use `ffmpeg` to do convert from gif to mp4.

Comment: Can it be, that your original image has already its minimal possible size? What about other images?